# Session based flash messages and restarting the session

Tags: php, session, message

I'm using a flash based message class to give the user messages.

In a particular page called Backup, the user can restore a backup and it will do the restore and then the following (the custom functions are rather self explanatory):

```
ASSession::destroySession();
ASSession::startSession();
$mg = new Messages();
$mg->add('s', $prepend);
redirect("login.php");
```

The issue as I saw it was that when we destroy the session we have to start a new one so that messages (which uses session variables to store the messages) will be displayed. However, once the user gets to the login page after the redirect the page calls a master 'framework' file that also calls `ASSession::startSession()`. So I figured I'd first check if we had a session id in the `startSession()` function, as we should have started the session before the redirect so there is no need to start a new session when we reach login as that would also remove the message before the user gets to view it.

So I made this change:

```
public static function startSession()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', SESSION_USE_ONLY_COOKIES);
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], SESSION_SECURE, SESSION_HTTP_ONLY);
        session_start();
        //session_regenerate_id(SESSION_REGENERATE_ID); 
    }
}
```

To no avail. I ran an entire site-wide find for `session_start()` to see if it was starting somewhere else without checking if it had already started and that came up negative. So my question is: why is my session restarting after I started it, if the only function that deals with starting the session checks if the session is currently running? Because my messages are not being displayed :(

Side note: I am trying to avoid the dreaded `?success='It worked'` and `echo $_GET['success'];`

Comment: Have you checked whether you have a session_id before creating your message (in the first snippet)? Also, check the session_id after redirect. I'm not sure if destroying and starting a session within one request might lead to side effects. You might want to regenerate session_id on session_start.

Comment: i get the same id before and after starting the session in the last snippet. and if i echo the session id before the redirect i get a different id than when i go to the login page. i can't check it with the redirect as, well, the page redirects too quickly. but destroying the session achieves the desired effect of logging the user out. what do you mean with one request? they are sep functions no?

Comment: What I meant was, that in your first snippet you do both: `ASSession::destroySession(); ASSession::startSession();` When you get a different id before the redirect it seems that restarting the session after destroy does not work correctly. Can you show the code of destroySession()?

Comment: It just removes a cookie and uses session_destroy () ; ... It's obviously working as the user is logged out and those vars are stored in session variables for the most part.